# AWS SageMaker: PermissionError: Access Denied - Reading data from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, error-handling, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS SageMaker. I already used it before and I had no problems reading data from an S3 bucket.
So, I set up a new notebook instance and id this:

```
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
role = get_execution_role()

bucket='my-bucket'

data_key = 'myfile.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)

df = pd.read_csv(data_location)
```

What I got is this:

```
PermissionError: Access Denied
```

Note: I checked the IAM Roles and also the policies and it seems to me that I have all the necessary rights to access the S3 bucket (AmazonS3FullAccess etc. are granted). What is different from the situation before is that my data is encrypted. Is there something I have to set up besides the roles?

Edit:

The role I use consist of three policies. These are

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonSageMakerFullAccess

and an Execution Role where I added kms:encrypt and kms:decrypt. It looks like this one:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "xyz",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there something missing?

Comment: Your role needs to have `kms:decrypt` permissions for the key for that bucket.

Comment: How do I amend or add this permission?

Comment: go to the IAM console, pick the proper role and add a new permission there, either for kms:decrypt for all resources * or figure out the specific kms key of the bucket.

Comment: Ok, I think I added the necessary permissions there but still get this error... The bucket is also publically accessible.

Comment: @luk2302: I edited my question. I would be glad if you could help :)

Comment: You need `kms:decrypt` on the kms key the bucket is encrypted with, not on the bucket itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230086/discussion-between-tobitor-and-luk2302).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add (or modify) an IAM policy to grant access to the key the bucket uses for its encryption:

```
{
  "Sid": "KMSAccess",
  "Action": [
    "kms:Decrypt"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:example-region-1:123456789098:key/111aa2bb-333c-4d44-5555-a111bb2c33dd"
}
```

Alternatively you can change the key policy of the KMS key directly to grant the sagemaker role access directly. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-access-default-encryption/

Comment: If you need cross-account access a S3 bucket whose data is encrypted, you need to modify the kms key policy in the key owning account, and create/update policy of an IAM in the key consuming account. See [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying-external-accounts.html)